# Enabling QGIS Atlas from QGIS Python Console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, atlas, qgis-python-console, atlas-generator

How can I enable the checkbox of atlas of print composer in QGIS 3.4, from Python Console in QGIS?

Here a image:

[image]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You have to search your layout (`lyt`) by name (`lytname`) in the layoutManager of the QgsProject instance, get the atlas and enable it :

```py
lytname = "mep"
lyt = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(lytname)
lyt.atlas().setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: Also, as I can activate Preview Atlas from Python Consoles.

Comment: `lyt.atlas().beginRender()`.